# How can I number centered text and formula combined?

Tags: equations, cross-referencing

I have some centered text and mathematical stuff:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
blablabla $\rho: H\longrightarrow GL_n(K)$ bla blabla bla blablablabla $H$ blabla blablabla blabla bla $\varphi:G\longrightarrow H$ blabla bla $\rho\circ\varphi:G\longrightarrow GL_n(K)$ blabla blablablabla bla $G$.
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Now, I'd like to give this piece of content a referable number, just like equations, and let the lines break automatically. I tried the following, but that didn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{blablabla $\rho: H\longrightarrow GL_n(K)$ bla blabla bla blablablabla $H$ blabla blablabla blabla bla $\varphi:G\longrightarrow H$ blabla bla $\rho\circ\varphi:G\longrightarrow GL_n(K)$ blabla blablablabla bla $G$.}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: Note that your `equation` does get numbered with your second code. The problem is that your line is just wayyyy too long. Exactly where you want to introduce line breaks is unclear, though.

Comment: @Jubobs: I'd like to let the lines break automatically.

Comment: You can use the [`breqn`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package. However, I think it conflicts with other commonly used packages. Anyway, I don't favour relying on automatic line-breaking; automatic line breaks rarely occur where you want them. I recommend you set the line breaks manually (e.g. using ``\\`` within a `split` environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the text in a `minipage`; if you want the number bottom aligned use `\begin{minipage}[b]{.8\displaywidth}`. Change the fraction to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
\begin{minipage}{.8\displaywidth}
blablabla $\rho\colon H\rightarrow GL_n(K)$ bla blabla bla blablablabla
$H$ blabla blablabla blabla bla $\varphi:G\rightarrow H$ blabla bla
$\rho\circ\varphi\colon G\rightarrow GL_n(K)$ blabla blablablabla bla $G$.
\end{minipage}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]